# Code coverage of JSR 303 validation annotations

Tags: code-coverage, bean-validation

I am unable to find a way that will give me a code coverage report for JSR 303 validation.

I've scoured the web and i cannot find a single reference to any attempted solution to this.
Im frankly at a complete and utter loss in how to attempt this.##

Would anyone know of way to attempt this?

Im ok with even changing my coverage tool if necessary. I use Cobertura and Jacoco.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't understand... 
Your JSR-303 validators are not covered ? 
Your JSR-303 beans are not covered ? 
 
I use Jacoco and both validator and beans are well covered. However I get an issue for my custom JSR-303 annotations.

Comment: For those of unfamiliar with JSR 303 but familiar with test coverage tools, what is you are trying to get coverage data for?  Test coverage is typically for *code*... but you can generalize the idea to other code-related artifacts (e.g. specifications). This is hard to implement if there isn't some kind of backwards traceability from code coverage data to "other artifacts".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the question is about validating that test cases cover all the expressed validation rules.  I'm using the xml configuration, and have the same question.

My best idea, so far, would be to use an aspect on the 
`<V extends ConstraintValidator>.isValid()` method (pardon the syntax), and use the `ContraintValidatorContext` to figure out which rule is being processed.  I haven't tried this, I'm not even sure this would work.